# Change from PHPmailer to sendmail

Tags: php, sendmail, phpmailer

I want to send the emails via original old school sendmail.

In what way i need to change this CODE to work with sendmail?

i have tried but i always get very ugly errors, i tried to change IsMail to IsSedmail but still does not send the original way.

Phpmailer sends 3 email and the website is taking a lot time to send, so i want to go to the old plain "mail(to...." but the problem is that i`m lost in all the code so please Help.

```
function send_mail($rec_email,$subject,$message, $IsHtml=false, $cc=array(), $bcc=array()) {
    global $THIS_BASEPATH, $btit_settings;

    if (!method_exists('PHPMailer','IsMail'))
        include($THIS_BASEPATH.'/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    $mail=new PHPMailer();

    if ($btit_settings['mail_type']=='php') {
        $mail->IsMail();                                   # send via mail
        if (!empty($cc))
            $mail->AddCustomHeader('Cc: '.implode(',',$cc));
        if (!empty($bcc))
            $mail->AddCustomHeader('Bcc: '.implode(',',$bcc));
    } else {
        $mail->IsSMTP();                                   # send via SMTP
        $mail->Host     = $btit_settings['smtp_server'];   # SMTP servers
        $mail->Port     = $btit_settings['smtp_port'];     # SMTP port
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                            # turn on SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = $btit_settings['smtp_username']; # SMTP username
        $mail->Password = $btit_settings['smtp_password']; # SMTP password
        if (!empty($cc))
            foreach($cc as $carbon_copy)
                $mail->AddCC($carbon_copy[0],$carbon_copy[0]);

        if (!empty($bcc))
            foreach($bcc as $blind_carbon_copy)
                $mail->AddBCC($blind_carbon_copy[0],$blind_carbon_copy[0]);
    }

    $mail->From     = $btit_settings['email'];
    $mail->FromName = $btit_settings['name'];
    $mail->CharSet  = $btit_settings['default_charset'];
    $mail->IsHTML($IsHtml);
    $mail->AddAddress($rec_email);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($btit_settings['email'],$btit_settings['name']);
    $mail->Subject  =  $subject;
    $mail->Body     =  $message;

    return ($mail->Send())?true:$mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Thank You very much.

Comment: first you say *sendmail*, then *mail()* the php function, theses are not the same thing

Comment: **comment** whole function code and place only `mail(to....)` with required parameters

Comment: PHPMailer can use mail(), bad idea, but it has configuration for that. basic example useing mail: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examplebsendmail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHPmailer is not the culrpit for "slowness", it's probably the SMTP server you've specified. Do not stop using PHPmailer, though. PHPmailer does *tons* of extra stuff behind the scenes to send mail *correctly*.

To send mail out through the local server using PHP's `mail()` replace:

```
$mail->IsSMTP();                                   # send via SMTP
$mail->Host     = $btit_settings['smtp_server'];   # SMTP servers
$mail->Port     = $btit_settings['smtp_port'];     # SMTP port
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                            # turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = $btit_settings['smtp_username']; # SMTP username
$mail->Password = $btit_settings['smtp_password']; # SMTP password
```

With:

```
$mail->isMail();
```

That's it.

If you are *certain* that the server has either Sendmail [or a drop-in replacement like Postfix or Exim] installed then you can use:

```
$mail->isSendmail();
```

However, by using the web server to send out mail you are now dependent on:

1. The installed MTA being configured correctly, which they frequently aren't.
2. The reputation of the web server according to various blacklists. Generally, web servers have s**t reputations because anyone can drop outbound mail into the queue without authentication.

Comment: Ok so i changed IsMail to IsSendmail now the website is working properly but is not sending the email, IsMail works but, is sending 3 emails instead of one and my hosting server gives an error that the website is curently down and to refresh the page in a minute.

Comment: In the end i searched for a free hosting website i added an email address and i used it as smtp server and works like a charm , Thank You for your Help.